# foreign model in User in django-allauth signup form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-allauth

I am using Django 1.8 and django-allauth. I use custom user model. 
I link the user model to Group, so I create my custom user model as follow:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
  email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='email address',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
  )
  group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

As you can see, group is a required field when a new user is created.

In the signup form, I put the default value to the group.

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    group = Group.objects.get(name='default')
    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.group = group
        user.save()
```

but it shows error when I try to sign up. Here is the error:

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/
(1048, "Column 'group_id' cannot be null")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/
Django Version: 1.8.3
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
(1048, "Column 'group_id' cannot be null")
```

So my question is how to save the required field "group" to the new user during signup as group is a required field in my user model.

Comment: Does Group.objects.get(name='default')  exist? And is that your entire SignupForm? If not, can you post the entire form.

Comment: That's my entire form. I am using django-allauth. I just need email address  and password to sign up. Email address and password are handled automatically by Allauth.

Comment: Right. Thanks for updating the post. Question though, does Group.objects.get(name='default') actually exist? Is there a group who's 'name' value is 'Default'?

Comment: Yes. it does exist. That's one of the group name.

Comment: Interesting. Can you post the model for Group? Edit: Also, try changing the ForeignKey field to "group = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank=True)". I'm curious as to if that will work (I don't expect it to, but for debugging purposes, it might help it, so might as well try it).

Comment: The Group is not my own model. It is from Django. (from django.contrib.auth.models import Group). In fact, I want Group to be required field so I didn't use blank=True. However, I have tried that, same error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually what I did is that I add a default value to Group field in the model. When a user signs up, it is automatically assigned to the default group.

```
  group = models.ForeignKey(Group, default='2') # id = '2' which is my default group.
```